# Any caveats to a runnable storing a reference to its own running thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a long running Runnable object and I wanted to provide a more graceful interrupt mechanism than having to call interrupt on the thread the object is running on.

The before code:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
        Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable, "myRunnableThread");
        t.start();

        //do stuff

        t.interrupt();

        //do stuff
    }
}
```

And the new code:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private Thread myThread = null;
    public void run() {
        myThread = Thread.currentThread();
        while(!myThread.isInterrupted()) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        if (myThread != null) {
            myThread.interrupt();
            //do other shutdown stuff
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
        Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable, "myRunnableThread");
        t.start();

        //do stuff

        myRunnable.shutdown();

        //do stuff
    }
}
```

My question is, are there possible side effects or unknowns that holding a reference to your own thread, and providing limited access to that thread through public methods (as above) could cause?  This is assuming that no-one ever calls the `run()` method directly, that it is always started from a new thread.

And I'm aware that I could use a volatile or atomic Boolean in the `run()` and `shutdown()` methods for communicating intent to shutdown, I'm more interested in learning than a solution.  But solutions are still welcome!

Comment: please note that `isInterrupted` is a method not a field

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Just a typo but you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your first approach is much better as less error prone and more "standard". But actually what you try to implement already exists (which proves that it makes sense and that it is not a bad practice but it is not easy to make it properly), it is called [`FutureTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html), instead of shutdown you have [`cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#cancel-boolean-) with `true` as value of `mayInterruptIfRunning` if you want to interrupt the thread running the task, I quote the javadoc:

> Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if
>   the task has already completed, has already been cancelled, or could
>   not be cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task
>   has not started when cancel is called, this task should never run. If
>   the task has already started, then the `mayInterruptIfRunning`
>   parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be
>   interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.

**For example:**

```
// Task that will only sleep for 1 sec and print a message on interrupted
FutureTask<Void> myRunnable = new FutureTask<>(
    new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            try {
                System.out.println("Sleep");
                Thread.sleep(1_000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted !!!");
                throw e;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
);
new Thread(myRunnable, "myRunnableThread").start();

// Wait long enough to make sure that myRunnableThread is sleeping 
Thread.sleep(500L);
// Cancel the task and interrupt myRunnableThread
myRunnable.cancel(true);
```

**Output:**

```
Sleep
Interrupted !!!
```

Comment: I looked into the `FutureTask` source code and they do store an internal reference to the currently executing thread, so at least if I use the reference similarly to how they do I shouldn't expect any wonkiness that they don't document.  I'm accepting this answer, even though it's more of a solution than an answer to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

It already has a reference:

```
Thread.currentThread()
```

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread--):

> Returns a reference to the currently executing thread object.

Comment: So your answer is that there are absolutely zero caveats/side effects for a Runnable to store a local reference to its executing thread, and providing public methods that use that thread?